# Using Tomcat with Maven in Eclipse throws errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jar

So I'm building a simple REST API with the help of Jersey. Up until now I have added all my jar files manually but then I found out about Maven and wanted to use that instead, thought It would make things easier. To run my API, I have just pointed eclipse to my Tomcat 8.55 folder. Now with the following configuration, my server works and I can reach my index.html at the root, but accessing any resource like `http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/api/v1/foo/bar always return 404.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>api-mashup-api</groupId>
<artifactId>api-mashup-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- Put dependencies below! -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[4.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- Put dependencies above! -->
```

This is my web.xml:

```
   <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>api</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

```
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>

  <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
```

So I figured that something ought to be wrong with my dependencies (I can't se any error though). I have searched for similar question and on the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html) I should add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- if you are using Jersey client specific features without the server side -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But that throws error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from your dependencies.
When you use a dependency with scope `provided`, it means that you are specifying this dependency to be used **ONLY** at compile time but at runtime, you are asking/expecting the servlet container(tomcat in you case) to provide these dependencies to run the application successfully.
But in Tomcat, these jars are not present. Hence you are getting `ClassNotFoundException`.
Also, using `<scope>provided</scope>` will not package these jars into your artifact.